# SQL Server : change tracking can retrieve previous version records

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I have configured my SQL Server database with change tracking feature. Currently I can retrieve table records information for latest version only.

How can I query the tables to get the previous version of the records? Hence that I can compare what data has been modified.

Please find my current query that am using to fetch the information.

```
DECLARE @last_synchronization_version bigint;

SELECT  
    CT.product_id, p.CLM_STAT_CD, p.DLR_CODE, p.DLR_NAME,  
    p.comments, p.INVOICE_NO, p.INVOICE_LINE_NO, p.INVOICE_ITEM_SUFFIX, 
    tc.commit_time, ct.sys_change_version, c.updated_by,
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT,
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION as TrackingVersion
FROM  
    dbo.product AS p  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.product, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT  
        ON p.product_id = CT.product_id
JOIN
    sys.dm_tran_commit_table tc ON CT.sys_change_version = tc.commit_ts
```

The above query is giving me the latest version changes information only. But I just want to check for the previous version changes also.

Comment: @last_synchronization_version is null so it shows you all the changes , the previous versions might be deleted due to the database tracking retention period limit and tracking changes auto remove settings.

Comment: @eshirvana i have give the retention period as 2 days but am updating the records on the same day twice. Ideally it should show all versions but it showing only the latest version.

Comment: You've picked the wrong tool for the job if you want all changes - [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#Tracking): "Change tracking captures the fact that rows in a table were changed, but does not capture the data that was changed"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - yea you are correct.!! Am using Azure SQL Database where we dont have `Change Data Capture` feature. Hence i started do some research on `Change Tracking` now i ended-up this issue. Is there anyother way available to get the data from all the versions of the same record.?

Comment: @Karthikeyan you might wanna look at [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) feature introduced in SQl server 2016 and its available in SQL Azure as well

Comment: SQL Change tracking is built to pull only the latest changes, so no way we can retrieve the previous version of the record. CDC is the best fit for your use case

Answer (score 0):

AS Damien_The_Unbeliever and eshirvana have pointed out in the comments, Change Tracking does not support version tracking. Since Change Data Capture is not supported in Azure SQL, Temporal tables seem to be a viable alternative.